# How can I call a function in my ios app once another ios app pushed a notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to call a function in my app when another app sent a notification. Can I download all the notifications to any database and use them? I am very new to ios development.

Comment: Explain more, what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless both apps are yours and you are able to change the app that is sending the notifications, the answer is "You can't". Apple does not allow apps access to other apps or to the system except in limited cases.

If you are able to modify the other app then you have a few options.